# Change Cefsharp Locale at runtime

Tags: cefsharp

You can't Cef.Shutdown() and reinitialize, you can't initialize multiple times so it seems you can't change the browser locale without completeley restarting your application.

The goal is to switch language of Cefsharp according to our application user language defined at login. E.g. Login with user German Cefsharp is in German, logout with User English Cefsharp should be in English but is still language of initialization.
[image: wrong language after logoff, login with different lang]

This [Github issue](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/574) about this topic exists and it is in state Closed. The issue says something about partially implemented and testing and is from the year 2015. I didn't find anything how to do this in C# code.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding to Mohammad Dimas answer.

`ChromiumWebBrowser` has a `IsBrowserInitializedChanged` event where you can obtain a `RequestContext`.

```
browser.IsBrowserInitializedChanged += Browser_IsBrowserInitializedChanged;

private void Browser_IsBrowserInitializedChanged(object sender, IsBrowserInitializedChangedEventArgs e)
{
        var browserHost =   browser.GetBrowser().GetHost();
        var requestContext = browserHost.RequestContext;
        string errorMessage = "";

        requestContext.SetPreference("intl.accept_languages", languageCode, out error);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Ok can you try this one? It will change the local language (`navigator.languages`) but not sure it will include that pdf viewer.

```
public static void SetLanguage(string languageCode)
{
    Cef.UIThreadTaskFactory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        using (var context = Cef.GetGlobalRequestContext())
            SetLanguage(languageCode, context);
    });
}

public static void SetLanguage(string languageCode, IRequestContext context)
{
    string error = null;
    var success = context.SetPreference("intl.accept_languages", languageCode, out error);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
        Log.WriteAsync(LogLevel.Error, string.Format("Error changing language: {0}", error));
}
```

Comment: I added more details to my question. This is useful too but I'm interested in changing the whole browser language. We use Cefsharp e.g. to display a PDF and the button hover texts stay in the initialized language. I guess it's because this has nothing todo with RequestContext

Comment: Tried it but besides a strange sideeffect because Cef.UIThreadTaskFactory is sometimes null it didn't change the language of the hover texts. Thanks anyway I think we will learn to live with this bug...